# Bounded output and Input matrix

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory

Suppose we have the following system:

\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
          0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
          0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
          -1 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
          \end{bmatrix}x + Bu
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y = Cx
\end{equation}
I want to find conditions on $B \in \mathbb{R}^{4\text{x}1}$ in order this system's zero state response to be bounded for all $C \in \mathbb{C}^{1\text{x}4}$ for  $u(t) = constant$. But isn't this the definition of BIBO stability? If it is, then since the eigenvalues of this system are $\lambda = \{-j,j\}$  this system cannot be BIBO stable since there will be no poles with negative real parts. If this is not equivalent to BIBO stability, then how can $y(t) = Ce^{At}Bu$ be bounded? There are $2$ jordan blocks with sizes $2$ and it would be almost impossible to get rid of $te^{jt}$ terms.

Comment: $B=0$ (zero vector) would work but that is probably not what you want.

Comment: @SampleTime, yes I'm looking for non-trivial cases.

Comment: You only want bounded output for $u(t)=constant$, or for any bounded input?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen only for the inputs of the form $u(t) = b$, where $b$ is constant.

Comment: I don't think this is the same as BIBO stability because of the "for all $C$" part (btw., with $C \in \mathbb{C}^{1\text{x}4}$ do you mean complex $C$?). The "for all $C$" would include the four cases $C=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix},C=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$,$C=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$,$C=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$. These four cases alone can only be bounded if the states $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are bounded so I don't think what you are asking for is BIBO stability.

Comment: @SampleTime, in fact this is stronger requirement as compared to BIBO stability. As I stated in the question, this system already cannot be BIBO stable. If this is the case, then how can we satisfy much stronger condition? And yes that means complex.

Comment: Is $B$ complex too?

Comment: @KBS, $B$ is real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First all, if you want the output to be bounded for all $C\in\mathbb{C}^{1\times 4}$, then this is equivalent to saying that it is bounded for all $C$ in $\{e_1^T,\ldots,e_4^T\}$ where the $e_i$'s are the vector of the natural basis for $\mathbb{C}^4$.

We have that

$$\exp(At)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} \cos\left(t\right)+\frac{t\,\sin\left(t\right)}{2} & \frac{3\,\sin\left(t\right)}{2}-\frac{t\,\cos\left(t\right)}{2} & \frac{t\,\sin\left(t\right)}{2} & \frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{2}-\frac{t\,\cos\left(t\right)}{2}\\ \frac{t\,\cos\left(t\right)}{2}-\frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{2} & \cos\left(t\right)+\frac{t\,\sin\left(t\right)}{2} & \frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{2}+\frac{t\,\cos\left(t\right)}{2} & \frac{t\,\sin\left(t\right)}{2}\\ -\frac{t\,\sin\left(t\right)}{2} & \frac{t\,\cos\left(t\right)}{2}-\frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{2} & \cos\left(t\right)-\frac{t\,\sin\left(t\right)}{2} & \frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{2}+\frac{t\,\cos\left(t\right)}{2}\\ -\frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{2}-\frac{t\,\cos\left(t\right)}{2} & -\frac{t\,\sin\left(t\right)}{2} & -\frac{3\,\sin\left(t\right)}{2}-\frac{t\,\cos\left(t\right)}{2} & \cos\left(t\right)-\frac{t\,\sin\left(t\right)}{2} \end{array}\right).$$

One can observe that the only way this remains bounded is by choosing $B$ such that the terms in $t$ cancel each other on each row. This is the case if and only

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\\-\alpha\\-\beta\end{bmatrix}$$

for any $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$. We have that

$$\exp(At)B = \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha\cos(t) + \beta\sin(t)\\
  \beta\cos(t) - \alpha\sin(t)\\
-\alpha\cos(t) - \beta\sin(t)\\
  \alpha\sin(t) - \beta\cos(t)
\end{bmatrix}$$

and we clearly have that $C\exp(At)B$ is bounded for all $C\in\mathbb{C}^{1\times 4}$. However, boundedness is not enough, what is important here is that the integral of this expression is bounded for all $t\ge0$ since we will be looking at the step response. This is obviously the case here.

Note that this is not equivalent to asking whether the system is BIBO stable because we are restricting ourselves to the case of constants inputs. The output will not be bounded for the input $u(t)=\sin(t)$ for instance even if $B$ is chosen as above. The concept of stability considered here is, in fact, weaker than BIBO stability.

---

**Additional questions from the comments:**

Is it possible to find the same result without having to compute the exponential $\exp(At)$?

Yes, this is definitely possible since $A$ and $\exp(At)$ have the same eigenvectors. The idea is that the matrix $B$ should be in the span of the eigenvectors of the eigenvalues on the imaginary axis but should not be in the span of the generalized eigenvectors.

In other words let $u_i$ be those eigenvectors, and it is necessary and sufficient that $B=\mathrm{span}\{u_1,\ldots\}$.

In the present case, we have that $(A-jI)u_1=0$ implies that $u_1=(j,-1,-j,1)$ and that $(A+jI)u_2=0$ implies that $u_2=(-j,-1,j,1)$. If we want to restrict to real matrices, we just choose $B$ to be in the span of $(u_1+u_2)/2$ and $(u_1-u_2)/(2j)$, and we find exactly the same result as above.

This easily generalizes to a general matrix $A$ where $B$ is in the span of

- the eigenvectors and the generalized eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalues with negative real part,
- the eigenvectors but not the generalized eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalues with zero real part, and
- no eigenvector and generalized eigenvector associated with the eigenvalues with positive real part.

Comment: I have couple of questions. Firstly, as you can imagine $e^{At}$ is very hard to compute by hand in this question. Can we infer $B$ by just calculating $e^{Jt}$ where $J$ is the jordan canonical form of $A$? Secondly, when $u(t) = sin(t)$, the response still seems to be absolutely integrable. Why do you say the output will not be bounded then?

Comment: @eet For your first question, yes it is possible but it is complicated to formulate simply (and it is late). So, I will need some time. For the second question, just compute the response of a system with impulse response $\sin(t)$ with input $\sin(t)$ and you will see what happens.

Comment: Yes, for some $C$ matrices you introduce $sin^2(t)$ terms which have integral with $t/2 - (sin2t)/4$. Clearly due to $t/2$ term, this would be unbounded.

Comment: Thanks KBS, appreciate it. That would be great if you can provide information about the jordan form I mentioned before, when you have time.

Comment: For the unboundedness, that can be seen from the fact that the gain of the system at the frequency $1$ is unbounded.

Comment: @eet Edited with an answer to your question.

Comment: what is the reason behind $B$ being in the span of some eigenvectors? Is this related to controllability?

Comment: @eet it is related to exciting only the simple part of the modes on the imaginary axis. But yeah it is also connected to the fact that the non-simple parts of the modes be non-controllable.

Comment: ++ By choosing normal eigenvectors but not the generalized eigenvectors, which modes are controllable now?

Comment: @eet I am sorry you are being difficult to understand. It also seems that some words are not correct. Please double check your comment before submitting it. What is the problem when the eigenvalues are on the imaginary axis?

Comment: My question is, what do you mean by simple part of the modes? And why do you excite only them? Does that related to $te^{\lambda t}$ terms in $e^{Jt}$? ($J$ is the jordan form)

Comment: It is the part that is "diagonalizable", that is for which there are eigenvectors. Check the terminology for eigenvalues (simple, semisimple, non-derogatory, etc.)

Comment: For instance, if $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, then there are two eigenvectors whereas for $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ there is only one.

Comment: Actually my question was why are non-simple parts of the modes uncontrollable?

Comment: @eet No, that was not your question. The answer is "by design". We explicitly choose the $B$ we want. This can be easily checked through calculations. Just do them. You can also simply draw the block diagram and see where the control input enters.